# Jibx JDK 17 Support

Tags: binding, jaxb, java-17, jibx, maven-jibx

I am currently working on creating a POC for a project that is currently in JDK 1.7 and uses Jibx. I am upgrading it to latest JDK 17 and am finding issues with Jibx "Could not instrument class mungeadapter". Is Jibx compatible with JDK 17, if not what must I need to do? Use Jaxb instead or what are the other options?

I don't see much support for jibx past JDK 1.7 and has me quite frustrated.

I have tried upgrading bcel jar in my project but is not helping.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jibx-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <directory>src/main/resources/jibx</directory>
                <includes>
                    <includes>binding_v1_1.xml</includes>
                </includes>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bind</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.bcel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcel</artifactId>
                    <version>6.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of JiBX. The current version should work fine with JDK 1.7. Please refer to the current Jibx maven plugin documentation at:
https://jibx.sourceforge.io/maven-jibx-plugin/usage.html

Comment: The question asks about Java 17, not Java 1.7.

Comment: JiBX is compatible with Java JDK 17 and Java JDK 1.7

Comment: @DonCorley is there any documentation for using JiBX with Java JDK 17 or do you know what versions are compatible with it?

Comment: The current version of JiBX is 1.4.2. This version is compatible with Java/JDK 1.5 through Java/JDK 19/1.9. Update your POM in the above example from 1.3.1 to 1.4.2. The documentation is the same for all versions.